# How spark behave if we use udf inside case when statement,does it apply the udf to all records then apply filter of case when?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I had written a query that call UDF function on some scenarios and for rest value it should give the else part. But as per physical plan, it shows it runs the UDF on all values of the column but then filter the records based on my 'when' condition.

Sample query:
Spark.sql("select *,case when col1 in ('1','2') then callUDF(col1) else col2 end from table")

So if col1 is in the list then the UDF should be called and return the value but in case it is not, then returns the other column value.

There is no issue you will face in normal scenario but in case your UDF require some set of values only then it fails as it is not expecting other values.

Is there any other workaround please share your thoughts.

Comment: you should handle this `col1 in ('1','2')` condition inside udf using `if else`?

Comment: It was actually col name comparison not the actual col value, so I am generating a dynamic sql where if particular column come under the list then check there value are under some list then call udf.